# debug misbehaving printer on Linux

Tags: linux, debian, printing, cups

I run debian testing and all of a sudden my Brother HL-1250 (connected via parallel port) stopped working properly.

What happens is that whenever I print something, all the printer does is to produce several pages, each page containing only one line of funny characters.

At first I thought it was a cups-related problem but after a lot of fiddling with it I cannot get rid of this problem.

So now I am trying to determine if it is cups that has a problem or rather the printer itself.

So I shut down cups and converted a pdf file into postscript (via pdftops) and well as to PCL (via gs) and send these files directly to the printer via the parallel device (e.g. "cat file.prn > /dev/lp1"), but the same behaviour persists.

Does that prove that the printer is faulty?

I there anything else I could try to figure out what the problem is?